# How do you install PyCallGraph / use pip?

Tags: python, pip, pycallgraph

and thanks to anyone who gives some of their time to consider my problem.

What I need help on is for someone to give me a simple and accessible explanation on how to install that module. I have never, ever used anything from PyPi before, I have only heard of pip after looking up [PyCallGraph](http://pycallgraph.readthedocs.org/en/master/).

I'm not a programmer first, I'm doing an accounting internship and am using python to write scripts to help me speed up some processes, at the urging of a colleague who himself uses python. I write scripts using Notepad++ and execute them through IDLE.

I'm currently working on optimizing a script I wrote and came upon [PyCallGraph](http://pycallgraph.readthedocs.org/en/master/) while checking this very site on tips on how to do so.

I tried the very minimalistic instruction of just doing "pip install pycallgraph" just about anywhere I could think of, including cmd.exe, to no avail. Runing get-pip.py directly seems to have worked for installing pip, though.

Otherwise I can always just stick with the cProfile printout and write-off using modules needing such an install, although that saddly seems to be quite a few...

Comment: You said you already know how to call `pip install pycallgraph`. Did you mean this command didn't succeed? And if it didn't what error did you get?

Comment: Also if you just run `pip` what does it say?

Comment: Okay, I think you are severely overestimating what I know. What did was :
1 - just copy 'pip install pycallgraph' after importing pip and seeing what happens(a SyntaxError).
2 - copying that into cmd.exe and seeing if that works.
3 - copying that into cmd.exe but prefaced by python
4 - typing python(after understanding that it called up the interpreter inside cmd.exe. Yeah, never really used cmd.exe before) and then importing pip before copying the line and trying to run it.
5 - same thing but writing 'run' before the whole thing

Comment: If it type pip into cmd.exe directly it tells me that it's not recognized(I would copy what it exactly says, but my Windows is in French so it probably wouldn't help).

If I first type python and import pip I get : <module 'pip' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.pyc'>

Comment: See my answer. You need to run `pip` commands from command-line, not from Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: Install PIP**

- Open terminal (`cmd.exe`, PowerShell, whatever)
- Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and place it in the working directory of your terminal
- Install PIP by invoking `python get-pip.py`
- Confirm that PIP was installed correctly by invoking command `pip` (should display help if success)
- If `pip` didn't work, make sure your PATH environment variable has been set up correctly. In typical Windows installations pip is installed under `c:\Python27\Scripts`. Make sure this folder is included in PATH.

**Step 2: Install your library with PIP**

- Invoke `pip install pycallgraph`
- PIP installs the library and it can be now used from Python

Comment: Step one works, it tells me that pip is already up to date and performs a cleanup.

For step two... I get something which roughly translates to "'pip' hasn't been recognized as an internal or external command, an executable programme or a command file."

Comment: Okay, I managed to find a post which explained what I needed to do, based on how you explained things. Since you said that pip on his own should display help(it displayed the message that it hasn't been recognized), I did check for pip + "hasn't been recognized" and managed to find another question here which told me that I needed to change my Path variable. After abit of googling I found the step by step guide for that on Java.com

Comment: Oh yeah you do need to setup PATH variable if that is not done!